# Listar objetos aleatorios

Tags: ruby, random, active-record, rails4

Como eu poderia gerar carros aleatorias no seguinte model?
seria melhor fazer isso no controller?

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :carros
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer um scope para trazer esses carros aleatoriamente. Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carros
end



class Carro < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pessoa
  scope :aleatorios, -> { limit(5).order('RANDOM()') }
end
```

Onde `5` no `limit` é a quantidade de `carros` que você deseja que seja retornado.

Assim você pode fazer, por exemplo:

```
pessoa = Pessoa.first
pessoa.carros.aleatorios
```

GG WP

Answer (score 1):

obrigado pela resposta fiz + ou - o que voce passou só que na class Carro < ActiveRecord e chamei o metodo na view dessa forma:

```
class Carro < ActiveRecord::Base 

    class << self def carro_random(n=4) 
        self.order('rand()').first(n) 
      end 
    end 
end
```